# Underfull warning in place where text wraps

Tags: tables, warnings, underfull

I created a table and I have multiple underfull warings in places where text wraps. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabulary} % Dla bardziej zaawansowanych tabel. Zawija automatycznie tekst
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[OT4]{polski} % pakiet języka polskiego
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %pakiet do przesuwania grafiki prawo/lewo
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pakiet do grafiki
%\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz} %pakiet do przekreślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %pakiet do kolorowania tablicy
\usepackage[showframe, margin = 2cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
%\makeatletter
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{hyperref} % %pakiet do wstawiania linków z kolorem
\usepackage{caption}    %for going to the top of an image when a figure reference is clicked
\usepackage[text= black, background = white , arrow = gray ]{callouts} % Dodawanie odnośników na figures - parametry 
\usepackage{tikz} % Rysowanie strzałek, odnośników na figures
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % Ustawienie, dzięki któremu możemy numerować rodziały z czterema miejsca (paragraph) np. 1.1.1.1, dla pieciu zmień 4->5
%\usepackage{parskip} parskip = 1pt
\usepackage{multirow} % Biblioteka dla scalania wierszy tabel
%\usepackage{pbox} % Biblioteka dla dodwania nowych linii, bez dodawania nowego wiersza w tabeli 
\usepackage{nicematrix} % Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage{calc}% Biblioteki do przekraślania komórek tabeli
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % Biblioteka dla przesuwania obrazków w prawą stronę
\usepackage{enumitem} % Biblioteka dla numeracji poprzedzonej literą
\usepackage{listliketab} % Biblioteka, dzięki której można wprowadzać numerację w tabeli
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tasks,blindtext}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage} % Zaczynanie rozdziału zawsze od nowej strony
\usepackage{float} % Pakiet używany w celu wymuszenia pozycjonowania tabeli/zdjęcia w miejscu wywołania
\restylefloat{table} % -||-
\usepackage{mdwlist} % pozwala na zawieszanie (suspend) i wznawianie numerowania (resume)
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % Usunięcie wcięć w nowych akapitach
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

```
    \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|} % c- wiersz wycentrowany, r - do prawej, l - do lewej
    \hline

    \rowcolor{yellow} %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
        \textbf{Dane ogólne}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{}  \\ 
        \hline 
        Wymiary (szer. x wys. x dł.) &  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{1300mm x 2600 x 3900}\\ 
        \hline 
        Waga, ok.   & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{1795kg  (szczegóły patrz 4.7)}  \\ 
        \hline \hline
        
        \rowcolor{yellow} %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
        \textbf{Elektryczność}& \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ }\\ 
        \hline

        \multirow[t]{6}{*}{Linia zasilająca 3P+N+PE }
        & Źródło zasilania: gniazdo sieci elektrycznej    & 400V AC 32A \\  \cline{2-3} 
        & Napięcie zasilania:                             & 400V AC 50Hz \\ \cline{2-3} 
        & Prąd znamionowy:                                & 24 A AC \\      \cline{2-3}  
        & Liczba faz:                                     & 3 \\            \cline{2-3}
        & Moc linii zasilającej:                          & 9,6 kW \\       \cline{2-3}    
        & Charakterystyka zabezpieczenia sieci:          &  C32 A \\   
        \hline 
        Inne wbudowane rodzaje zasilania                 & Napięcie sterowania & 24VDC \\ 
        \hline \hline

        \rowcolor{yellow} %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
         \textbf{Parametry pracy}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ }  \\ 
         \hline
         Dokładność prostowania nóżek  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{$\pm$ 0,2mm }  \\ 
         \hline
         Maksymalny ciężar przenoszonego komponentu.  &  \multicolumn{2}{|p{10cm}|}{13gram (cięższe komponenty zostaną upuszczone przez chwytak podciśnieniowy)}  \\ 
         \hline
         Czas cyklu maszyny  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Dla 1toru 3s/komponent,} \\
          & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Dla 2torów pracujących jednocześnie 1,5s/komponent}  \\ 
         \hline \hline

         \rowcolor{yellow} %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
         \textbf{Hałas}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Pomiar $L_{EX,8h}$=64dBA (+2,0dBA)}  \\ 
         \hline \hline

         \rowcolor{yellow} %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
         \textbf{Oświetlenie}  &  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ }  \\ 
         \hline
         Oświetlenie maszyny & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Zgodne z wymaganiami normy PN-EN 12464-1}} \\ 
         \hline
         Oświetlenie pomieszczenia/hali  & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Zgodne z wymaganiami normy PN-EN 12464-1} \\
         & \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Natężenie oświetlenia w zakresie od 300 do 500luksów. } \\
         \hline \hline 

         \rowcolor{yellow}
         \textbf{Warunki otoczenia}  &  \textbf{Transport i magazynowanie} & \textbf{Praca}  \\\hline 
         Temperatura/wilgotność & 5°C do +50°C / 35-85 & +18°C do +32°C / 50-75 \\
         & Uwaga! czułe elementy elektroniczne & Uwaga! czułe elementy elektroniczne    \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Comment: Dear Anna, please merge your code fragments to one, small but complete document, which reproduce your problem, It should be MWE; Minimal Working Example, which we can test as it is.

Comment: MWE: Reduce the table as much as possible, while showing that (and only that) warning problem. Remove all packages that and anything else that is not mandatory to produce a document with only that table. Make sure that the code that you posted can be compiled "as is".

Comment: BTW, warning is just warning and it not harm ... However, please test if the following specification of your table remove it:  `\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}`.

Comment: As long, as your content changes, i.e. you're in the process of writing, such warnings will come and go. Save such fine-tuning for the finalizing phase, if at all.

Comment: You may want to replace tabular by tabularx, and the formattings p by at least one X. See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx .

Answer (score 1):

Your table using `tblr` of `tabularray` package and `siunitx` for writing of quanaties on consistent way. <no warning, no bad boxes ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{3}{X[l]}},
             colsep  = 3pt,
             hspan = minimal
             }
\SetRow{yellow}
\textbf{Dane ogólne}            
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}                                  
        &                                           \\    
Wymiary (szer. x wys. x dł.)    
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  \qtyproduct{1300 x 2600 x 3900}{mm}    
        &                                           \\
Waga, ok.                       
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  \qty{1795}{kg}  (szczegóły patrz 4.7)             
        &                                           \\
    \hline 
\SetRow{yellow} %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
\textbf{Elektryczność}
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}                              
        &                                           \\
    \hline
\SetCell[r=6]{l}    Linia zasilająca 3P+N+PE
    & Źródło zasilania: gniazdo sieci elektrycznej      
        & \qty{400}{\volt} AC \qty{32}{\ampere}     \\ 
    & Napięcie zasilania:                             
        & \qty{400}{\volt} AC \qty{502}{\hertz}     \\ 
    & Prąd znamionowy:                                
        & \qty{24}{A} AC                            \\ 
    & Liczba faz:                                     
        & 3                                         \\
    & Moc linii zasilającej:                          
        & \qty{9,6}{\kilo\watt}                      \\ 
    & Charakterystyka zabezpieczenia sieci:          
        &  C32 A                                    \\
    \hline
Inne wbudowane rodzaje zasilania                 
    & Napięcie sterowania 
        & \qty{24}{V} DC                            \\
    \hline 
\SetRow{yellow} %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
\textbf{Parametry pracy}  
    &  \SetCell[c=2]{c}
        &                                           \\
Dokładność prostowania nóżek  
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  \qty{\pm 0,2}{\milli\meter} 
        &                                           \\
Maksymalny ciężar przenoszonego komponentu.  
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  \qty{13}{gram} (cięższe komponenty zostaną upuszczone przez 
                                        chwytak podciśnieniowy)
        &                                           \\
Czas cyklu maszyny  
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  Dla 1toru 3s/komponent,\par
                        Dla \qty{2}{torów} pracujących jednocześnie 
                        \qty{1,5}{\second/komponent}
        &                                           \\
     \hline 
\SetRow{yellow}     %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
\textbf{Hałas}  
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  Pomiar $L_{EX,8h}=\qty{64}{dBA}\ (+\qty{2,0}{dBA} )$ \\
        &                                           \\
    \hline
\SetRow{yellow}     %pokolorowanie całego następnego wiesza
\textbf{Oświetlenie}  
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c}
        &                                           \\
    \hline     
Oświetlenie maszyny 
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  \textbf{Zgodne z wymaganiami normy PN-EN 12464-1} 
       &                                           \\
Oświetlenie pomieszczenia/hali  
    & \SetCell[c=2]{l}  Zgodne z wymaganiami normy PN-EN 12464-1\par
                        Natężenie oświetlenia w zakresie od \qtyrange{300}{500}{\lux}. 
        &                                           \\
    \hline
\SetRow{yellow}     
\textbf{Warunki otoczenia}  
    & \textbf{Transport i magazynowanie} 
        & \textbf{Praca}                            \\
Temperatura/wilgotność 
    & \qtyrange{5}{50}{\degreeCelsius} / 35-85 
        & \qtyrange{18}{32}{\degreeCelsius} / 50-75  \\
    & Uwaga! czułe elementy elektroniczne 
        & Uwaga! czułe elementy elektroniczne       \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate document pages layout)